# Asp.net nested virtual directory inherits resource assemblies from parent

Tags: asp.net, directory, nested, virtual

In my hosting I have an asp.net website called WebsiteA which works ok.
I have created a virtual directory in WebsiteA called WebsiteB and published another website.
The problem is that WebsiteB tries to access the globalreousrces (and local resources) from WebsiteA bin folder instead of its own bin folder.

I have already fixed the error of inheriting the web.config of the parent by adding the following in WebsiteA's web.config.

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
```

How do I tell WebsiteB to access its own assemblies?
Please note that both website are published and work ok as root directories. The problem is nesting them.

Comment: You probably want to make it an application instead of just a virtual directory. Not sure if it will still try to inherit things though since I've never played with nested applications like that.

Comment: I cannot change that since I am on a shared hosting.

Comment: I'm not sure there will be a lot you can do then. The whole point of a subdirectory being a virtual directory rather than a virtual application is that a virtual directory is logically part of the parent site. If it were a virtual app then it would be saying "I am an entirely new application from here". You might want to check with your host if you can make virtual directories into apps.